# Split a file into parts to parallel download with pycurl

Tags: python, multithreading, download, pycurl

I want to download a file with pycurl in python. So I want to find a way to download it in multiple parts that increases the speed of downloading. I know in theory it is the same as downloading the file in one part but it seems it's faster to download it in several parts concurrently.

Comment: How do you figure that _in theory it is the same as downloading the file in one part_? It's quite different, it uses a `Range: bytes=0-999` header in the request and the response will be a `206 Partial Content`. But only if the web server supports range requests, as indicated by the `Accept-Ranges` header. The other question is if `pycurl` supports ranged requests.

Comment: I read something about this here and there that it's the same, maybe I made a mistake.
I think `pycurl` supports ranged requests. Would you please explain how to work with `Range` header, and is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: As for your second question, no, ranged requests are the only way to download a file in multiple parts.

Comment: It seems [curlwrapper](https://github.com/pythonben/curlwrapper/) is an (unfinished) wrapper around pycurl that makes use of ranged requests. See [browser.py](https://github.com/pythonben/curlwrapper/blob/master/curlwrapper/browser.py) and [basebrowser.py](https://github.com/pythonben/curlwrapper/blob/master/curlwrapper/basebrowser.py). So it does seem to have some support for it, but you'd probably have to take care of stitching the file parts together yourself. I don't use `pycurl` myself, so unfortunately I can't give you a concise example.

Comment: For HTTP range requests in general, this is a pretty decent explanation: [HTTP Status: 206 Partial Content and Range Requests](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/)

Comment: If you can, use another protocol than HTTP. Using `nc` (netcat) I've been able to easily saturate a 100 Mbit/s ethernet link.